# Memory leak in Visual Studio 2012 using ReSharper on 'huge' Solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper

For some major codecleanup I created a Solution including all projectfiles to make things easier.
This is roughly 620 .csproj with about 12k Source-Files.

Using the cleanup on this solution will surely take ages, but that was planned. Unplanned however was the SystemOutOfMemory-Exception during the process.

Im not sure whether this is resharpers fault or visual-studio itself (noticed similiar problems with ex. CodeMaid)

I monitored taskmanager and rightbefore it was throwing the exception, memoryusage was at ~ 2.6Gb. It grew constantly during the process, so this must be some kind of "not freeing ressources thing"

Is there anything that can be configured to get rid of this problem ? Like some option that disables any kind of caching or whatever?

I know splitting up in smaller solutions would work...

Comment: What version?  Each new version generally has memory fixes/improvements.

Comment: Try turnin off resharper and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Visual Studio is 32 bit only. It is very easy to hit the memory barrier for huge solutions and I don't think there is much to do except cutting your solutions down.

Comment: 620 projects? Pretty sure VS will grind to a halt long before R# gets a chance to also grind to a halt.

Comment: @Peter Richie Latest resharper.

Answer (score 1):

We also have an extremely large solution file that, unfortuantely, I have to deal with daily.  There are some configurations you can change with resharper and vs to speed things up that should also help save on memory usage.  The below link helped me some:
https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546919

Comment: Link requires login AND is broken once you do login.

Comment: Link should be fixed now.